# How to make a 'function' like the For loop

Tags: javascript

I have taken a lot of time looking for this, and I believe someone else already answered it. I just don't know where/how to search for it. So I thought I would ask it here.

I just want to know if it is possible and how to make different functions/statements like the If statement or the For loop. What I would like to do it make a function called inArray. You would put an array in the parameters and then in the actual function part you could tell it what you want it to do.
That was a little confusing so I'll just show you want I want.

```
//Here is what I want work
inArray (array) {
    //My function...
}

//Here is something I could do, but I don't like the way this is done.
inArray(array, func)
function func() {
    //My function...
}
```

I know I could do this with other JS codes, but I want to try making this to understand JS better. Thanks for any answers you give.

Comment: There are many functions on [`Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) that perform a variety of iteration tasks for arrays.

Comment: What I mean is, is there a way to make a function in the format like an If statement/for loop. I don't know how to word this, sorry.

Comment: You cannot create new basic syntax in JavaScript, if that's what you're asking. You can write all the functions you want and design them to work with objects and other functions.

Comment: If i understood your question you can read this argument on mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

Comment: No, this is not possible. You can of course write `inArray(array, function () {
    /* My function... */
})` or `inAray(array, () => { … })`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use sweet.js to achieve this kind of behavior (create new operators).
https://www.sweetjs.org/

Comment: I wanna note that, as cool as this project is, it's probably best not to use custom syntax in production, or if you're in a team with others, which is a good way to descend into complete confusion over what any non-obvious thing does. But if it's a small personal pet project, go for it ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯

Comment: I totally agree with you @kingdaro